# JAVASCRIPT : Empty array after foreach loop

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, loops, foreach

I'm working on a NestJSxMongoose store management project.

I have this piece of code in which I want to update some items in the database and put those updated items in an array that I will use later.

```
const updatedItems: Item[] = [];

purchaseData.items.forEach(async (purchasedItem) => {
  const itemInDB = await this.itemService.findItemByName(purchasedItem.name);

  itemInDB.quantity -= purchasedItem.quantity;

  const updatedItem = await this.itemService.updateItem(
    itemInDB['_id'],
    itemInDB
  );

  updatedItems.push(updatedItem);

  console.log(updatedItems); // Output : [{actual_data}]
});

console.log(updatedItems); // Output : []
```

The issue I have is that when I log the content of *updatedItems* inside the *forEach()*, it contains the actual expected data. But when I try to use it outside the *forEach()* loop, it logs an empty array. I want to use that array outside of the *forEach()*.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `await` not works on `forEach` use `for` or `for of`, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop?rq=1)

Comment: @1sina1 , Oh okay that's what I did not know. I will try to use for or for of from now on when working with async operations. I got a better understanding now, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait for results, you have to write it like this: Get the array of all promises and awaits them.

.forEach (as well as .map) runs synchronously. If you pass async function as a parameter, it does not `await` them, it just executes them to the nearest await and then returns (still unresolved) promise.

Therefore the `console.log(updatedItems); // Output : []` is executed before the logic inside async function.

```
const updatedItems: Item[] = [];

const promises = purchaseData.items.map(async (purchasedItem) => {
  const itemInDB = await this.itemService.findItemByName(purchasedItem.name);

  itemInDB.quantity -= purchasedItem.quantity;

  const updatedItem = await this.itemService.updateItem(
    itemInDB['_id'],
    itemInDB
  );

  updatedItems.push(updatedItem);

  console.log(updatedItems); // Output : [{actual_data}]
});

await Promise.all(promises);

console.log(updatedItems); // Output : []
```

Here you can see the order of execution:

```js
const purchaseData = { items: [1,2] }

purchaseData.items.forEach(async (purchasedItem) => {
  console.log('first', purchasedItem);
  await console.log(); // the awaiting console log does nothing, it is just to trigger the beaviour of async function when it hits await
  console.log('third', purchasedItem);
});

console.log('second');
```

Comment: Oh right, thank you for taking the time to explain. Now I have a better understanding of how async operations work. I tried the solution you provided and it's now working as expected, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` expects a synchronous function. If an asynchronous callback is passed to it, the synchronous parts of the program (here, your second `console.log`) will be executed before executing the callback awaited lines. [Pay attention to this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description).

It is better to put the whole iterative parts in an asynchronous function and use a `for` loop instead of `forEach` inside it, and then write the `console.log` after calling the asynchronous function.

```
const updatedItems: Item[] = [];

async function updateData(){
    for (let index = 0; index < purchaseData.items.length; index++) {
       const itemInDB = await this.itemService.findItemByName(purchaseData.items[index].name);

       itemInDB.quantity -= purchasedItem.quantity;

       const updatedItem = await this.itemService.updateItem(
           itemInDB['_id'],
           itemInDB
       );

       updatedItems.push(updatedItem);

       console.log(updatedItems);
   }
}

await updateData();
console.log(updatedItems);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it better now. I'll try using a for loop instead. Kudos !

Answer (score 0):

Use Async and await its not waiting till the loop its going to next you need to wait until the loop finish

```
async function updateItemFun() {
const updatedItems: Item[] = [];

await purchaseData.items.forEach(async (purchasedItem) => {
  const itemInDB = await this.itemService.findItemByName(purchasedItem.name);

  itemInDB.quantity -= purchasedItem.quantity;

  const updatedItem = await this.itemService.updateItem(
    itemInDB['_id'],
    itemInDB
  );

  updatedItems.push(updatedItem);

  console.log(updatedItems); // Output : [{actual_data}]
});

console.log(updatedItems); // Output : []
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. And then i should call this function right after ?